# notifyDataSetChanged() resetting scroll state in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to implement `notifyDataSetChanged()` and keep the scroll state in a `RecyclerView`? I already tried with `notifyItemChanged()` and `notifyItemRangeChanged()` but with the same results.

Answer (score -1):

`notifyItemRangeChanged(0,adapter.getItemCount());`